# How to pass unknown children of Polymer component into component's DOM

Tags: javascript, polymer, web-component, polymer-1.0

I want to create a component which I can pass other components to and create DOM structures.

```
<test-component>
    <img/>
    <div/>
    <foo/>
</test-component>
```

In trying to get that working:

```
<dom-module name="test-component">
    <template>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <ul>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{nodes}}">
                <li>element:</li>
                <li>{{item}}</li>
            </template>
        </ul>

        <content id="contentelement"></content>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer({
        is: "test-component",
        ready: function() {
            this.nodes = (function(that) {
                var nodeList = that.$.contentelement._distributedNodes,
                    nodeMap = [];
                for(var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++) {
                    if(nodeList[i].nodeType === 1) {
                        nodeMap.push(nodeList[i].outerHTML);
                    }
                }
                return nodeMap
            }(this));
        }
    });
</script>
```

I used a function to build this.nodes because
    this.nodes = this.$.contentelement.getDistributedNodes();
returns null, not sure why.

I know you can't just drop an element's outerHTML into the page but can a random set of HTML/components be passed into a template like this?

Comment: If you are doing DOM manipulations, you can use `Polymer.dom(this)` to access the light dom while `Polymer.dom(this.root)` for local dom. This is actually the preferred way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible with data-binding (have a look at this [discussion on Github](https://github.com/Polymer/TemplateBinding/issues/57)).

Here's a possible workaround in JavaScript.

```
<dom-module name="test-component">
    <template>
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <ul>
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{nodes}}">
                <li>element:</li>
                <li class="content"></li>
            </template>
        </ul>
        <content id="contentelement"></content>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Polymer({
        is: "test-component",
        ready: function() {
            this.nodes = this.getContentChildren();
            this.async(function(){
                var contentNodes = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(".content");
                this.nodes.forEach(function(element, index) {
                    contentNodes[index].innerHTML = element.outerHTML;
                });
            }.bind(this));
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Edit**

You can remove the content nodes from their original location after you have accessed them by removing them from the DOM.

```
this.nodes = this.getContentChildren();
Polymer.dom(this.root).removeChild(this.$.contentelement);
```

Comment: Above works brilliantly, but for one more question. can content.content element be hidden? (at least for me, it renders the structure I'm looking for, then the content as passed in)
as in is there a proper way or is it just a question css display?

Comment: @io41 apart from your CSS solution, you could also remove the nodes from the DOM. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Thank you Maria. This was a perfect set of answers and really helped me out.